# Index View conflict between ICollection and IEnumerable

Tags: c#, html, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a Create and Edit View set up to use Pull Down boxes to enter data from relational tables. I have a mix of 1 to Many and Many to 1 links from the Critvit Table, and can't get them to work together on the Index View.

Critvit Model

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace NextRung.Models
{
    public class Critvit
    {
        public Int32    CritvitId { get; set; }
        public Int32    RoleId { get; set; }

        public decimal? Salary { get; set; }
        public decimal  RoleExp { get; set; }
        public Int32    SkillId { get; set; }
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public DateTime? StartDate { get; set; }
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }
        [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
        public DateTime? CreateDate { get; set; }
        public string   Summary { get; set; }
        public Int32    CompanyId { get; set; }

        // AuditInfo
        public Int32 UserId { get; set; }
        [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
        public DateTime? CreatedDate { get; set; }
        [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
        public DateTime? EditedDate { get; set; }
        [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
        public DateTime? DeletedDate { get; set; }



        public virtual ICollection<Role> Roles { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Skill> Skills { get; set; }
        public virtual User Users { get; set; }
        public virtual Company Companies { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Index View

```
@model ICollection<NextRung.Models.Critvit>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Companies.CompanyName)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Users.Email)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Roles.RoleTitle)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Salary)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.RoleExp)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Skills.SkillName)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.StartDate)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.EndDate)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Summary)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Companies.CompanyName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Users.Email)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Roles.RoleTitle)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Salary)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.RoleExp)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Skills.SkillName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.StartDate)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EndDate)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Summary)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.CritvitId }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.CritvitId }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.CritvitId })
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

This code appears to let the RoleTitle and SkillName fields work but not the Email or CompanyName.

I can switch  `@model ICollection<NextRung.Models.Critvit>` with `@model IEnumerable<NextRung.Models.Critvit>`

If I use RoleId and SkillId, IEnumerable works fine, but this isn't what I need. Every solution I've tried so far only works for some of the fields.
So, how can I get the Index View to display the relational data in all 4 fields instead of just 2?

Comment: Roles and skills are having multiple objects, how can you use `model.Skills.SkillName`? I suppose each skill should be having different SkillName, right?

Comment: Use List instead of Icollection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the model use List for roles and skills.

```
public virtual List<Role> Roles { get; set; }
public virtual List<Skill> Skills { get; set; }
```

In view iterate over the list to each value from these lists as below

```
<th>
@foreach(var r in model.Roles)
{
<p>
    @Html.DisplayNameFor(r.RoleTitle)
</p>
}
</th>
<th>
@foreach(var s in model.Skills)
{
<p>
    @Html.DisplayNameFor(r.RoleTitle)
</p>
}

</th>
```

Comment: no, but i prefer list, enumerable doesnt work sometime in views

Comment: Doesnt work how? A list typed into an Ienumerable functions the exact same way as typed into a list disregarding some methods you have access to.